# How to bypass angular2 security, custom pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I have content returned from my database to view:

```
some blog text  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Sanhp_td4Uw" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen></iframe> More blog text.
```

What I want to do is let the iframe display the embedded video in my content.
As you can see, it just displays as a string.

So I went ahead and created this pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({
  name: 'safehtml'
})
export class SafehtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
  transform(value: any, args?: any): SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}
```

And am using it in my template as :

```
<div [outerHTML]="pageBlg.blog | safehtml"></div>
```

But this didn't change anything.
[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AHzqXAagWnDCAtNNmP8B?p=preview)